# php openssl_sign with ES256 creates invalid signature

Tags: php, jwt

I'm trying to create a jwt token with ES256 signature. Here's the relevant part of code:

```
private function base64UrlEncode(string $data): string
{
    $urlSafeData = strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_');
    return rtrim($urlSafeData, '=');
}

public function token(Request $request):JsonResponse
{
   [...]

    $header = $this->base64UrlEncode(json_encode([
        "alg" => "ES256",
        "typ" => "JWT",
        "kty" => "EC"
    ]));

    $payload = $this->base64UrlEncode(json_encode($data));

    if (!\is_readable(__DIR__.'/private_key.pem'))
    {
        //create new private and public key
        $new_key_pair = openssl_pkey_new(array(
            "digest_alg" => \OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256,
            "private_key_bits" => 2048,
            "private_key_type" => \OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_EC,
            "curve_name" => "prime256v1"
        ));
        openssl_pkey_export($new_key_pair, $private_key_pem);

        $details = openssl_pkey_get_details($new_key_pair);
        $public_key_pem = $details['key'];
        //save for later
        file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/private_key.pem', $private_key_pem);
        file_put_contents('public_key.pem', $public_key_pem);
    }
    $private_key_id = \openssl_pkey_get_private('file://'.__DIR__.'/private_key.pem');

    //create signature
    openssl_sign($header.'.'.$payload, $signature, $private_key_id, \OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

    $token = $header.'.'.$payload.'.'.$this->base64UrlEncode($signature);
    [...]
}
```

But the generated signature is invalid when testing on jwt.io. Any suggestions what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: openssl\_verify not working with ECDSA keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433799/php-openssl-verify-not-working-with-ecdsa-keys)

Comment: The problem is that the signature should be the concatenation of R and S, but OpenSSL return a PKCS#1 signature i.e. there are additional information that lead to a false negative verification.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Funny thing is openssl_verify() says  the signature generated by openssl_sign() is valid, but any online jwt validator i found say it's invalid. "the signature should be the concatenation of R and S, but OpenSSL return a PKCS#1 signature" can you point me to a direction with more information about this? Any workaround?

Comment: Use this: https://github.com/web-token/jwt-framework/blob/v1.1/src/Component/Core/Util/ECSignature.php
The static method `ECSignature::toDER` wil convert the signature from your token to an acceptable signature for openssl_verify. For `ES256`, the `$partLength` argument is 64.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work, because the generated signature's length is not fix, each request returns different signature with length between 70-72, and after unpack this goes to 140-144, and never 128 as the code expects thus i'm getting InvalidArgumentException all the time

Comment: Maybe my private key is wrong somehow?

Comment: `$signature = ECSignature::fromDER($signature, and 64);` have to be placed just after your `openssl_sign` call. You should also check that OpenSSL did not failed during the computation of the signature

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended up using the whole web-token/jwt-framework lib, and works fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737488/apple-sign-in-sign-jwt-for-authentication-using-php-and-openssl

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apple Sign In "invalid\_client", signing JWT for authentication using PHP and openSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737488/apple-sign-in-invalid-client-signing-jwt-for-authentication-using-php-and-ope)