# Apple Sign In "invalid_client", signing JWT for authentication using PHP and openSSL

Tags: php, android, openssl, jwt, apple-sign-in

I'm trying to implement Apple sign in into an Android App using this [library](https://github.com/willowtreeapps/sign-in-with-apple-button-android). The main flow is described in the documentation: the library returns an authorization code on the Android side. This authorization code has to be sent to my backend which, in turn, sends it to the Apple servers in order to get back an access token.

As described [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple) and [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/apple-sign-in-custom-servers-and-an-expiry-conundrum-d1ad63223870), in order to obtain the access token we need to send to the Apple API a list of parameters, the authorization code and a signed JWT. In particular, JWT needs to be signed with a ES256 algorithm using a private .p8 key which has to be generated and downloaded from the Apple developer portal. [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/generate_and_validate_tokens)

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php

$authorization_code = $_POST('auth_code');

$privateKey = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
my_private_key_downloaded_from_apple_developer_portal (.p8 format)
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
EOD;

$kid = 'key_id_of_the_private_key'; //Generated in Apple developer Portal
$iss = 'team_id_of_my_developer_profile';
$client_id = 'identifier_setted_in_developer_portal'; //Generated in Apple developer Portal

$signed_jwt = $this->generateJWT($kid, $iss, $client_id, $privateKey);

$data = [
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'client_secret' => $signed_jwt,
            'code' => $authorization_code,
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
        ];
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$serverOutput = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

var_dump($serverOutput);

function generateJWT($kid, $iss, $sub, $key) {

    $header = [
        'alg' => 'ES256',
        'kid' => $kid
    ];
    $body = [
        'iss' => $iss,
        'iat' => time(),
        'exp' => time() + 3600,
        'aud' => 'https://appleid.apple.com',
        'sub' => $sub
    ];

    $privKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($key);
    if (!$privKey) return false;

    $payload = $this->encode(json_encode($header)).'.'.$this->encode(json_encode($body));
    $signature = '';
    $success = openssl_sign($payload, $signature, $privKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
    if (!$success) return false;

    return $payload.'.'.$this->encode($signature);
}

function encode($data) {
    $encoded = strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_');
    return rtrim($encoded, '=');
}

?>
```

The problem is that the response from Apple is always:

```
{"error":"invalid_client"}
```

Reading [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123723) it seems that the problem could be related to openSSL which generates a signature which is not correct for Apple ("*OpenSSL's ES256 signature result is a DER-encoded ASN.1 structure (it's size exceed 64). (not a raw R || S value)*").

**Is there a way to obtain the correct signature using openSSL?**

**Is the p8 format the correct input for the openssl_sign and openssl_pkey_get_private functions?**
(I noticed that the provided .p8 key does not work if used in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) in order to compute the signed jwt.)

In the openSSL documentation I read that a pem key should be provided, **how can I convert a .p8 in a .pem key?**

I also tried with some PHP libraries which basically use the same steps described above like [firebase/php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) and [lcobucci/jwt](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt) but the Apple response is still "invalid client".

Thank you in advance for your help,

**EDIT**

I tried to completely remove openSSL from the equation. Using the .pem key generated from the .p8 one I have generated a signed JWT with jwt.io. With this signed JWT the Apple API replies correctly. At this point I'm almost sure it's an openSSL signature problem. The key problem is how to obtain a proper ES256 signature using PHP and openSSL.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As indicated [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123723), the problem is actually in the signature generated by openSSL.

Using ES256, the digital signature is the concatenation of two unsigned integers, denoted as R and S, which are the result of the Elliptic Curve (EC) algorithm. The length of R || S is 64.

The openssl_sign function generates a signature which is a DER-encoded ASN.1 structure (with size > 64).

The solution is to convert the DER-encoded signature into a raw concatenation of the R and S values. In [this library](https://github.com/web-token/jwt-framework/blob/v1.1/src/Component/Core/Util/ECSignature.php) a function "*fromDER*" is present which perform such a conversion:

```
    /**
     * @param string $der
     * @param int    $partLength
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function fromDER(string $der, int $partLength)
    {
        $hex = unpack('H*', $der)[1];
        if ('30' !== mb_substr($hex, 0, 2, '8bit')) { // SEQUENCE
            throw new \RuntimeException();
        }
        if ('81' === mb_substr($hex, 2, 2, '8bit')) { // LENGTH > 128
            $hex = mb_substr($hex, 6, null, '8bit');
        } else {
            $hex = mb_substr($hex, 4, null, '8bit');
        }
        if ('02' !== mb_substr($hex, 0, 2, '8bit')) { // INTEGER
            throw new \RuntimeException();
        }
        $Rl = hexdec(mb_substr($hex, 2, 2, '8bit'));
        $R = self::retrievePositiveInteger(mb_substr($hex, 4, $Rl * 2, '8bit'));
        $R = str_pad($R, $partLength, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $hex = mb_substr($hex, 4 + $Rl * 2, null, '8bit');
        if ('02' !== mb_substr($hex, 0, 2, '8bit')) { // INTEGER
            throw new \RuntimeException();
        }
        $Sl = hexdec(mb_substr($hex, 2, 2, '8bit'));
        $S = self::retrievePositiveInteger(mb_substr($hex, 4, $Sl * 2, '8bit'));
        $S = str_pad($S, $partLength, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        return pack('H*', $R.$S);
    }
    /**
     * @param string $data
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private static function preparePositiveInteger(string $data)
    {
        if (mb_substr($data, 0, 2, '8bit') > '7f') {
            return '00'.$data;
        }
        while ('00' === mb_substr($data, 0, 2, '8bit') && mb_substr($data, 2, 2, '8bit') <= '7f') {
            $data = mb_substr($data, 2, null, '8bit');
        }
        return $data;
    }
    /**
     * @param string $data
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private static function retrievePositiveInteger(string $data)
    {
        while ('00' === mb_substr($data, 0, 2, '8bit') && mb_substr($data, 2, 2, '8bit') > '7f') {
            $data = mb_substr($data, 2, null, '8bit');
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Another point is that a .pem key should be provided to the open_ssl_sign function. Starting from the .p8 key downloaded from the Apple developer I have created the .pem one by using openSSL:

```
openssl pkcs8 -in AuthKey_KEY_ID.p8 -nocrypt -out AuthKey_KEY_ID.pem
```

In the following my new *generateJWT* function code which uses the .pem key and the fromDER function to convert the signature generated by openSSL:

```
    function generateJWT($kid, $iss, $sub) {
        
        $header = [
            'alg' => 'ES256',
            'kid' => $kid
        ];
        $body = [
            'iss' => $iss,
            'iat' => time(),
            'exp' => time() + 3600,
            'aud' => 'https://appleid.apple.com',
            'sub' => $sub
        ];

        $privKey = openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents('AuthKey_.pem'));
        if (!$privKey){
           return false;
        }

        $payload = $this->encode(json_encode($header)).'.'.$this->encode(json_encode($body));
        
        $signature = '';
        $success = openssl_sign($payload, $signature, $privKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
        if (!$success) return false;

        $raw_signature = $this->fromDER($signature, 64);
        
        return $payload.'.'.$this->encode($raw_signature);
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is it! I've been searching for problem causing "invalid client." Correct solution. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome explanation, Andrea! I had been battling inconsistent authentication problems with MapKit Snapshots for days before I came across your answer. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Andrea, I have added code to my php one but when I try to make request to apple it always says invalid client. Can you please let me know what is wrong ? I am using php 5.5 version.

Comment: @Hardik it's hard to say without seeing your settings.... I can suggest you to double check the parameters and keys, are you converting the .p8 key in a .pem one?

Comment: @Andrea, I got private key from apple and its starts with ---BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY like that one. Is that correct one ? what is .p8 format ?

Comment: @Hardik The key is provided by Apple in the .p8 format. If you want to use the open_ssl_sign function you need to convert the .p8 key downloaded from the Apple Portal in a .pem one using the instruction provided in the answer.

Comment: I've converted my p8 key to a pem one, copied the code but  Andrea Gorrieri forget 'encode' function personaly I have`public function encode($data){
     return str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($data)); 
    }` and the key is used like that  `$pem_content =
"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----XXX----END PRIVATE KEY-----";$privKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($pem_content);` but I have a `{"error":"invalid_client"}`

Comment: You can find the 'encode' function in the question, just below the 'generateJWT' function