# Creating jwt after signing with apple in php

Tags: php, curl, jwt

I've a question about signing with apple more precisely how to create the jw token in php after logging, here is what I do:

```
$pem_content = 
"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----".
"XXXX".
"-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
$header = json_encode(array(
  'kid' => $keyId,
  'alg'  => 'ES256'
));
$decodedTokenData =  json_decode(base64_decode(str_replace('_', '/', str_replace('-','+',explode('.', $_POST['id_token'])[1]))),true);

$payload = json_encode(array(
    'iss' => $teamid,
    'iat' => time(),
    'exp' => time() + 86400*180,
     'aud' => $decodedTokenData['aud'],
    'sub' => $decodedTokenData['sub'],
));
$base64UrlHeader = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($header));
$base64UrlPayload = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($payload));
$key = //I don't know how to use $pem_content here
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload, $key, true);
$base64UrlSignature = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($signature));
$jwt = $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload . "." . $base64UrlSignature;
```

And to test transaction I do

```
curl -X POST https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token -d  '{"client_id":$CLIENTID,"client_secret":$jwt,"code": $_POST['code'],"grant_type":"authorization_code","redirect_uri":$URL}'
```

But I get

```
{"error":"invalid_client"}
```

Two constraints here: I must use only php and avoid external libs

Thanks in advance

EDIT I generate jwt like this:

```
$signature = '';
openssl_sign($base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload, $signature,openssl_get_privatekey($pem_content),'SHA256');
$signature = $this->signatureFromDER($signature, 256);
```

the functions used are from here https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/d2113d9b2e0e349796e72d2a63cf9319100382d2/src/JWT.php#L172

and now curl command is

```
curl -X POST "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token" -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d"client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&code=CODE&grant_type=authorization_code&redireect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsite.com%2Findex.php"
```

But I still get invalid_client

EDIT2:
I've nom implemented this solution:
[Apple Sign In "invalid_client", signing JWT for authentication using PHP and openSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737488/apple-sign-in-invalid-client-signing-jwt-for-authentication-using-php-and-ope)

But I keep having invalid_client error

EDIT3
even with https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt I get the error

Comment: Take a look at the implementation here: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/d2113d9b2e0e349796e72d2a63cf9319100382d2/src/JWT.php#L172. One thing that jumps out is the use of `openssl_sign` for `ES256` instead of `hash_hmac`.

Comment: Oh and one thing that may be tripping you up is that, according to the docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens) the body of that POST to `https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token` should be of type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Thanks for your help msbit, now I do 
`$signature = '';
openssl_sign($base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload, $pem_content,'ES256');
$signature = $this->signatureFromDER($signature, 256);`
The jwt is valid (I've teste it on https://jwt.io), but I still have an 'invalid_client'

Comment: Typo, 
`openssl_sign($base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload, $signature,$pem_content,'ES256');`

Comment: typo ,  `alg` missing endquote.

Comment: ok fixed (it was just a typo here not in the code)

Comment: Have you looked into changing the POST to use the correct content-type (ie not a JSON blob, but form data)?

Comment: You mean something like this?:
 `curl -X POST "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token" -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d'client_id=$client_id'  -d 'client_secret=$jwt' -d'code=$code' -d 'grant_type=authorization_code' -d 'redirect_uri=$uri'`

Comment: Are you sure you want to implement this all on your own? Why not use any existing library for this?

Comment: I've tried this library
https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/tree/d2113d9b2e0e349796e72d2a63cf9319100382d2
`$jwt = JWT::encode($payload, openssl_pkey_get_private($pem_content),'ES256',$keyId,$header);`
but still invalid_client

Answer (score 4):

So the problem was the the sub value

Here is the code for generating jwt:

```
function generateJWT() {
        $kid =  "...";
        $iss = '...';
        $sub = '...';
        $header = [
            'alg' => 'ES256',
            'kid' => $kid
        ];
        $body = [
            'iss' => $iss,
            'iat' => time(),
            'exp' => time() + 3600,
            'aud' => 'https://appleid.apple.com',
            'sub' => $sub
    ];

    $pem_content = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
XXXXX
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
EOD;
        $privKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($pem_content);
        if (!$privKey){
           return false;
        }

        $payload = $this->encode(json_encode($header)).'.'.$this->encode(json_encode($body));

        $signature = '';
        $success = openssl_sign($payload, $signature, $privKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
        if (!$success) return false;

        $raw_signature = $this->fromDER($signature, 64);

        return $payload.'.'.$this->encode($raw_signature);
    }

    public function encode($data){
        return str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($data)); 
    }      

    public static function fromDER(string $der, int $partLength)
    {
        $hex = unpack('H*', $der)[1];
        if ('30' !== mb_substr($hex, 0, 2, '8bit')) { // SEQUENCE
            throw new \RuntimeException();
        }
        if ('81' === mb_substr($hex, 2, 2, '8bit')) { // LENGTH > 128
            $hex = mb_substr($hex, 6, null, '8bit');
        } else {
            $hex = mb_substr($hex, 4, null, '8bit');
        }
        if ('02' !== mb_substr($hex, 0, 2, '8bit')) { // INTEGER
            throw new \RuntimeException();
        }
        $Rl = hexdec(mb_substr($hex, 2, 2, '8bit'));
        $R = self::retrievePositiveInteger(mb_substr($hex, 4, $Rl * 2, '8bit'));
        $R = str_pad($R, $partLength, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $hex = mb_substr($hex, 4 + $Rl * 2, null, '8bit');
        if ('02' !== mb_substr($hex, 0, 2, '8bit')) { // INTEGER
            throw new \RuntimeException();
        }
        $Sl = hexdec(mb_substr($hex, 2, 2, '8bit'));
        $S = self::retrievePositiveInteger(mb_substr($hex, 4, $Sl * 2, '8bit'));
        $S = str_pad($S, $partLength, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        return pack('H*', $R.$S);
    }
    /**
     * @param string $data
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private static function preparePositiveInteger(string $data)
    {
        if (mb_substr($data, 0, 2, '8bit') > '7f') {
            return '00'.$data;
        }
        while ('00' === mb_substr($data, 0, 2, '8bit') && mb_substr($data, 2, 2, '8bit') <= '7f') {
            $data = mb_substr($data, 2, null, '8bit');
        }
        return $data;
    }
    /**
     * @param string $data
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private static function retrievePositiveInteger(string $data)
    {
        while ('00' === mb_substr($data, 0, 2, '8bit') && mb_substr($data, 2, 2, '8bit') > '7f') {
            $data = mb_substr($data, 2, null, '8bit');
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Saved the day @Camile Gallet. Worked Smoothly

Comment: Code is working perfectly